# Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с шириной инпутов

Tags: css

Помогите разобраться с инпутами при при ширине < 350px
https://jsfiddle.net/ngoo5y1q/

```
form
   div
      input


width: 100%;
max-width: 362px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.form-registration > div > input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Иди даже так:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: @идентикон, прими ответ галочкой слева.